# Find root of two conditional function with Python

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I have a function with two input variables (x,y) that retun two values that are related to each other I want The best algroithm to find the roots (x,y) that makes retuning values equal to zero

def EQU(x2,y3):
#Alot of structural engineering calcuation
return Mx,My

I try to solve one seprtly by fixing one equation and variable and solve the other in a loop but I need to more fast algorithm and work

```
def bisect(f, a, b, n , v , tol=1e-6, max_iter=100):    
    if n == 0 :        
        if f(a,v)[0] * f(b,v)[0] >= 0:
            a = a - Lx

        for i in range(max_iter):
            c = (a + b) / 2
            if f(c,v)[n] == 0 or (b - a) / 2 < tol:                   
                return c
                
            elif f(c,v)[0] * f(a,v)[0] < 0:
                b = c
            else:
                a = c
        #"Exceeded maximum iterations! - no root found."
    else:
        if f(v,a)[1] * f(v,b)[1] >= 0:
            a = a - Ly

        for i in range(max_iter):
            c = (a + b) / 2
            if f(v,c)[1] == 0 or (b - a) / 2 < tol:                   
                return c
                
            elif f(v,c)[1] * f(v,a)[1] < 0:
                b = c
            else:
                a = c
        #"Exceeded maximum iterations! - no root found."
    return None

x2final = 0.5*Lx
y3final = 0.5*Ly
for i in range (100):
    x2in = x2final
    y2in = y3final
    x2final = bisect(EQU, 0, 0.95*Lx , 0 , y3final )
    y3final = bisect(EQU, 0, 0.95*Ly , 1 , x2final )
    print(x2final,y3final)

    if abs(x2in-x2final)<10e-6 and abs(y2in-y3final)< 10e-6:
        break
```

Comment: Why not use the solvers of scipy.optimize, like the general solver fsolve? Moving along the coordinate axes using bisection is among the slowest variants that exist.

Comment: The general solver idea is that you take a point or a collection of points and their function values and derivatives and build a linear, quadratic,... model. In conjunction with that you also get or update a radius of how far this approximation is valid. Then from the model find a direction towards its root, move there or stop at the boundary of the trust region. Add the found point and some in its neighborhood to the collection, remove some other points and start anew. A classical method along these lines is SQP, sequential quadratic programming. Other trust-region methods exist.

Comment: Thanks, but could someone write a code that works foe my program?